# How Can I Use The HTML Button Element In JavaScript Completely

Tags: javascript, html

Can You help me find out how to use the html button element in JavaScript because

```
    document.write("<body> <div>  </div> </body>")
```

is not working for buttons or drop down menus so can you help me?
my guess is the

```
    .write
```

Is the problem because that probably means text and a button is not text.

Comment: I would stop using `document.write` it has been surpassed by many much more useful manipulation methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most correct way to do this. You must create elements and add them to the DOM tree.

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.append(button);

button.onclick = () => {
   alert('button clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `append()`. This example is stolen from [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

```
let parent = document.createElement("div")
let p = document.createElement("p")
parent.append(p)

console.log(parent.childNodes) // NodeList [ <p> ]
```